# Google map appears only after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am unable to make my google map load after I load my page. Every time I have to refresh in order for it to apppear and I don't understand the reasons for that. Can someone help?

Here is my html(a bit simplified)

```
<div id="lblContact" class="menu-content">
<div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the script :

```
   <script>
     function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 55.682121, lng: 12.522697};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
            });
          }
 </script>

 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC_absRIQusU2qV5pLwxf3zyIlspwe9Wwc&callback=initMap">
 </script>
```

p.s

I tried changing the order of the scripts, which didn't help.

Comment: Where do you call `initMap`? I see it being defined but I don't see it being called. Maybe adding `$(document).ready(function() {initMap();});`?

Comment: @MarcCompte, I have a callback=initMap in the second script.

Comment: I see now. Maybe it is calling it before the HTML has been fully loaded? If you remove the callback parameter and add the jquery onload, does it work?

Comment: No, i tried tried with document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {}); and it didn't work

Comment: If what you tried is exactly as suggested in an answer below then check again. In that answer they use `DOMContentLoaded` to declare the function. Which means that it may be declared after the Google API finishes loading, so by the time they call `callback` that function has not been defined yet. Declare the function outside the event trigger and call it from within.

Comment: okay, i will try to figure this out...

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code as it is in a code snippet and it works. If it doesn't on your machine you'll need extra testing and debugging. Do you have an error message in the Javascript console? https://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code with this `DOMContentLoaded` function, it will only run once the DOM has loaded and should fix your problem, it's the vanilla JS equivalent of jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){})` if you're familiar with that:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 55.682121, lng: 12.522697};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
            });
          }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: how about with that and the api script called first?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var uluru = {lat: 55.682121, lng: 12.522697};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC_absRIQusU2qV5pLwxf3zyIlspwe9Wwc&callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="lblContact" class="menu-content">
<div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: you should open and check for errors in developer's options of your browser.